# ¿Como actualizar datos?

Tags: c#, sql-server, modal

Amigos,tengo un problema.Tengo un gridview que al seleccionar una de sus filas,este me abre una ventana modal y me llena varios textbox con los datos de la fila.Todo eso funciona bien.El problema es que quiero actualizar esos datos,pero no me funciona el código que he armado para actualizar hace nada.

Aqui mi codigo:

```
  protected void btnactualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection ( "Data Source = MEGATRON; Initial Catalog = RentCar; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("UPDATE Autos SET Marca = @Marca, Modelo = @Modelo, Subnombre = @Subnombre,Año = @Año, NoPuertas = @NoPuertas, TipoCombustible = @TipoCombustible,TipoTransmision = @TipoTransmision, CapacidadAsientos = @CapacidadAsientos, Precioxdia = @Precioxdia" + " where Codigo =@ID ",con);// repeat for all variables


            con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtCod.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marca", idmarca.SelectedItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modelo", DropDownListModelo.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subnombre", txtSufijo.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Año", DropDownano.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoPuertas", NoPuertas.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoCombustible", txtCombustible.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipotransmision", DropDownListtransmision.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Capacidadasientos", txtAsientos.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color", DropDownListColor.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Precioxdia", txtPrecioxdia.Text);
                    // repeat for all variables....

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();


    }
```

Comment: el codigo es correcto..

Comment: @gbianchi Pero cuando hago clic en el boton btnactualizar,no hace nada.

Comment: El código es correcto, deberías mirar en la base de datos si existe el `@ID` que le estás pasando al `update`